# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in sinh when using ODEINT and solve_bvp to solve Poisson–Boltzmann equation

Tags: numpy, runtime-error, ode, odeint

Because the solution to the spherically symmetric Poisson-Boltzmann (PB) equation is an electric potential (psi) that decays to 0 at large distances (r -> infty), I set my boundary condition so that psi=0 at my final distance value for solve_bvp. My initial condition is that psidot decays coulombically at r = r0, where r0 is the radius of my central ion. However, the decaying function is a hyperbolic sin, which decays to 0 at small psi values, but never to actually 0. I believe this is the source to both solvers having trouble with the hyperbolic sin. Any idea how to overcome this?

[Click here for PB equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trsde.png)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp, odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(r,x,a,b):
    y = x[0]
    dy = x[1]
    xdot = [[],[]]
    xdot[0] = dy
    xdot[1] = -2/r*dy + a*sinh(b*y)
    return xdot

# boundary conditions for solve_bvp:

def bc(at0, at1, a, b):
    # Values at r=initial:
    yat0, ydotat0 = at0

    # Values at r=final:  
    yat1, ydotat1 = at1

    # These return values are what we want to be 0:
    return [ydotat0 - ydot0, yat1]

# initial condition for ODEINT
y0 = z*e/(4*pi*eps*r0)
ydot0 = -z*e/(4*pi*eps*r0**2)

r = np.linspace(r0,100*r0,201)

C1 = 0.1 #molar concentration
a = 2*e*C1*Nav*1000/(eps) #2eC/eps
b = e/(k_b*T) #e/kT 

ystart = odeint(model,[y0,ydot0],r, args=(a,b,), tfirst=True)

result = solve_bvp(lambda x,r: model(x,r,a=a,b=b), lambda at0, at1: bc(at0,at1,a=a,b=b), r, ystart.T)
```

output:

```
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in sinh
  
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_bvp.py:40: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  hi = y_new[i] - y[i]
```

Comment: The domain admissible for floating point evaluation of the exponential and consequently the hyperbolic sine is rather small, with an upper limit below 1000. If the solver produces trial solutions outside that range you get an error. Replace the sinh with a function that is exact for arguments to 200 and then continues linearly or with some other cut-off.